# Разделить строку по заданным индексам

Tags: python, строки, list, index

Простейшее задание, но поверхностный поиск не дал ответа, потому пришлось задавать вопрос.

Итак, у нас есть строка: "pythoniscool,isn'tit?"

есть список цифр: [6, 8, 12, 13, 18]

Необходимо разбить строку по индексам, указанным в списке:

["python", "is", "cool", ",", "isn't", "it?"]

Вот мое решение:

```
s = "pythoniscool,isn'tit?"
a = [6, 8, 12, 13, 18]
a = [0]+ a + [len(s)]
print([s[a[i]:a[i+1]] for i in range(len(a) - 1)])
```

уверен, что оно "некрасивое" и не оптимальное, может уважаемые пользователи подскажут еще?

Comment: нормальное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение хорошее, могу только предложить оптимизировать сам вывод, заменив индексацию списка `a` его двойным перебором со сдвигом, мне кажется это выглядит менее громоздко (хотя возможно менее оптимально по скорости, но это нужно проверять):

```
print([s[i:j] for i, j in zip(a, a[1:])])
```

Кроме того, можно не вычислять длину строки для последнего среза, а просто написать `None`:

```
a = [0] + a + [None]
```

В принципе, поскольку в одном переборе нам не нужен конец, а в другом начало, то можно перенести это добавление в сам перебор, будет ещё чуть красивее (конструкция `[1:]` мне не очень нравится):

```
# a = [0] + a + [None]
print([s[i:j] for i, j in zip([0] + a, a + [None])])
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Вполне себе годное решение.

Ради академического интереса можно накидать других решений с использованием дополнительных модулей, например:

```
import numpy as np
arr = ''.join(np.insert(np.array(list(s)), a, " ")).split()
```

arr:

```
['python', 'is', 'cool', ',', "isn't", 'it?']
```

но эти решения вряд ли будут более элегантными.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!